# Rapahel js paper.print() with position specified in percentage terms

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I am using raphaeljs to create a SVG editor for a website, i cant use fixed position in pixels because the same web page need to be accessed from iphone, ipad  etc. so `paper.print(120,120,"Hello","font-name",80);`
cannot be used, i need some thing like `paper.print("3%","4%","Hello","font-name",80);`
which is not supported by raphael library i think,
Any suggestion , how can i achieve what i want?

Answer (score 0):

Start thinking in percentages rather than pixels. Before you "introduce" your editor you need to locate your editor responsively.
Suppose your editor has a standard width of 400px and your text is at 420px both these locations will be X pixels from the left margin.
You can replace your first parameter with an X +20 value. All you need to do is determine the width of the viewport at load to determine the first parameter for your cross device editor.
Here's an example of a Carousel which always fits in a device viewport (Even down to an iPod).
It uses the same technique..
[Responsiveness with vectors](http://www.irunmywebsite.com/visualdesign/ffc.php)